# Moving and rotating object with another object

Tags: 3d, mathematics, geometry

[image]

Sorry i bad painter))

Need move and rotate 'OBJECT №2' with 'OBJECT №1'

I have origin point(also rotation point) and angles of two object. (Also min and max coordinates of these objects)

Vector origin, Vector angles, Vector absmin and Vector absmax.

I tried next simple code, and it works nice, if object angles not changed:

```
object2.origin += object1.origin - object1.oldorigin;
```

(without rotation)

But i need also rotation, I was rarely attend geometry at school, and can't do it without help )))

Comment: What do you mean to rotate object1 *with* object2? You mean to rotate object2 *around* object1? Or to rotate them around a common point? Please try to improve the clarity of the question.

Comment: This looks very similar to [your recent question answered here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/172044/39518). If the answer you accepted there didn't solve your problem, can you clarify where you've run into trouble using it in this situation?

Comment: No this ansfer very bad and unreadable )

Comment: Then instead of accepting it, you should add a comment explaining what didn't work for you, so that either the original author or other users know what kind of help you need and can offer you answers that are more helpful to you. Don't re-post the same question again: if you want to clarify what you're asking, edit your original question.